# $((A\iff B)\land(C\implies A))\implies((A\iff B)\land(C\implies(A\iff B)))$?

Tags: logic

Note: I changed the meaning of this question after posting.

I have used a shortcut in my notes which I am unsure is a correct use of logical notation.  Since my notes were originally written only for my use, that hasn't presented a problem, since I know what I meant.  But lately, I've been inclined to do things right, regardless of whose watching.

What I do is, if I have a situation in which I have an equivalence between two terms, say $A\iff B,$ and I also have the implication $C\implies A,$ as a shortcut I write $C\implies\left(A\iff B\right)$ to mean

$$\left(\left(A\iff B\right)\land\left(C\implies A\right)\right)\implies\left(C\implies B\right).$$

Yesterday I convinced myself that this is wrong.  Today I convinced myself that it is, in fact correct.  I believe my mistake yesterday was that I was omitting the second instance of $\left(A\iff B\right)$ in

$$\left(\left(A\iff B\right)\land\left(C\implies A\right)\right)$$

$$\implies\left(\left(A\iff B\right)\land\left(C\implies\left(A\iff B\right)\right)\right).$$

So I am now asking if the immediately above two-line statement is correct?  And does it mean

$$\left(\left(A\iff B\right)\land\left(C\implies A\right)\right)\implies\left(C\implies B\right)?$$

Comment: It is not a tautology. When A and B are False but C is True, then $((A\leftrightarrow B)\land( C\to A))$ is False but $((A\leftrightarrow B)\land(C\to(A\leftrightarrow B))$ is True.

Comment: I just wrote up the truth table and realized the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true, but I don't think it has the same notational purpose that you intend. $C\implies (A\iff B)$ does not tell you that $C\implies A$; you cannot deduce $C\implies A$ from this.

Similarly, $C\implies A$ doesn't help you conclude $C\implies (A\iff B)$. This follows purely from the $A\iff B$ being true.

You don't actually use your assumption that $C\implies A$ at all. The following is a true, reduced form of your statement:

$(A\iff B) \implies ((A\iff B) \land (C \implies (A\iff B))$

Since if you have $P$ you can always show $Q\implies P$ for any $Q$ trivially.

In fact, these two statements are *exactly* the same, so we can even slap in an iff arrow.

$(A\iff B) \iff ((A\iff B) \land (C \implies (A\iff B))$

As you can see, it doesn't really say anything strong at all. You should not get into the habit of using this (much weaker) statement as notation for the other.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what my question should actually be.  Since, I removed all of the cases where I was using in recent notes, I need to find older versions to compare.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if what you are asking is this:

Are $(A \leftrightarrow B) \land (C \rightarrow A)$ and $(A \leftrightarrow B) \land (C \rightarrow B)$ logically equivalent?

Or, even more general: If $S(\varphi)$ is a propositional logic statement that has $\varphi$ as a component statement, and if $S(\psi)$ is the result of substituting $\psi$ for $\varphi$, then are $(\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi) \land S(\varphi)$ and $(\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi) \land S(\psi)$ equivalent?

The answer is yes: any valuation sets $(\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi) \land S(\varphi)$ to True if and only if it sets $\varphi$ and $\psi$ to the same truth value, and $S(\varphi)$ to True, which is if and only if it sets $\varphi$ and $\psi$ to the same truth value, and $S(\psi)$ to True, and thus if and only if $(\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi) \land S(\psi)$ to True.

Comment: I believe what I actually want is: $\left(\left(C\implies A\right)\land\left(C\implies\left(A\iff B\right)\right)\right)\iff\left(C\implies\left(A\land A\iff B\right)\right)$  I'm working on a question along those lines right now.